# How to set a decorator for a function generated by executing a string using exec in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, exec, decorator

Here is my orginal code:

```
import latexify
@latexify.with_latex
def dt1(x):
    return   x^2+x+1

eq = dt1._latex 
print(eq)
```

As a result, \mathrm{dt1}(x) = x \oplus {2} + x + {1}  is printed.
It works fine, however, when I change the way to define the function in a string and use exec to generate dt1, I got error. The changed code is :

```
import latexify
string_with_func = '''@latexify.with_latex
def dt1(x):
    return   x^2+x+1'''
exec(string_with_func)
eq = dt1._latex 
print(eq)
```

And the error is
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\source.py:176 in findsource
raise IOError('could not extract source code')

OSError: could not extract source code

The content of the function like x^2+x+1 comes from the input of GUI, so different input will lead to diffenrent function dt1. Thus, I can not define dt1 just like usual. And I have to use the @latexify.with_latex decorator to get the latex form of function dt1.
So is there any way to apply @latexify.with_latex to the function dt1 generated by exec(string_with_func)?

Answer (score 0):

**REMEMBER:** This piece of code can be very risky and **not** recommended if you don't have proper verification steps for it.
[`ast.liteal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is claimed to be safe but there is no proper validations for it.

```
import latexify
if some_value_is_submitted_in_gui:
    def verify(string):
        '''Verify if the expression is an equation so no malicious code can be executed'''
        pass
    @latexify.with_latex
    def dt1(x):
        return  eval(verify(gui_input))
    
    eq = dt1._latex 
    print(eq)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think you suggest to use eval at return. So the code is now import latexify
@latexify.with_latex
def dt1(x):
    return   eval('x^2+x+1' )

eq = dt1._latex 
print(eq)        ,    and the result of print is "\mathrm{dt1}(x) = \mathrm{eval}\left(\textrm{"x^2+x+1"}\right)", it is not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foo
def bar(....): ...
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
def bar(....): .....
bar = foo(bar)
```

So if you want to apply a decorator, you can just apply it yourself as a function call, rather than using the decorator syntax.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem here is the function is defined by using exec, I didn't explicitly define to function dt1. Even I tryied latexify.with_latex(dt1), it will produce the same error.